# How to Replace Exterior Door & Casing in Old House

Tags: doors, exterior, trim, jamb

My house is about 100 years old. The door jamb is about 10" wide. I've replaced a few doors before, but all of them had standard jams. I'm not sure how to go about replacing this. I'm assuming I need to pull all of the trim & casing out, then pull the brick-molding off the door frame, then slide the frame all of the way back flush with the inside wall. Mount the frame, then re-install casing & trim. Also, i'm not sure where I stop removing the trim & casing at the top, since there is a top-light above the door. Below are a few pics.

Please help point me in the right direction.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you must replace that door, and it's in as good condition as it seems, make sure it gets reused rather than trashed. Freecycle, or donate to a place like Habitat's re/Stores, or find a use for it yourself... Or make the current frame more attractive, optionally sand and refinish the door (I suspect there's nice wood under the stain), re-hang it, and add a screen/storm door.

Answer (score 2):

The basic procedure for removing a door is: remove casing, remove screws from jamb/brick mold, and push the door out of the hole, brick mold still attached. Unfortunately your situation calls for some more devious tactics. Because the outer molding appears to be part of the transom casing (assuming you're leaving that part alone) you're probably better off not disturbing it. So you have to remove the interior trim, remove any screws that connect the jamb to the substructure, then very carefully prize the jamb away from the outer molding with a bar such as this:
[image]
to keep from marring the backside of your brick mold.
Once the door is out, the problem then becomes finding a new door/jamb that fits the opening not just properly but perfectly in order to get the reveals right, which may be a challenge considering how old and...unique your existing door is. If you over come that hurdle, just caulk the backside of the brick mold with sealant (sealant not caulk) and follow the manufacturers instructions for sealing the threshold and all should be well. Cheers!

Comment: Custom-size doors can be ordered, prehung or "slab"...